# bad practices in statistics - ratio of a ratio

Tags: logic, fallacies

I haven't been able to think of good search terms for my question, and I'm happy to be redirected to another stackoverflow site.

I frequently see statistics presented in scientific summaries (written for the general public) that use what I would call "ratios of ratios".  Is this always bad?  Is there a general term for this is a misleading technique?

Here is a made-up example to explain what I mean:

If my agenda to make people worried about lightning and make them afraid of being outdoors I might say something like:

The risk of being hit by lightning is 10 times greater when you go outside!

You can see that "risk" would be a percentage and 10x would be a ratio.  Such comparisons don't seem to be very useful when the base ratio (like lightning risk) is very large or very small.

Is there a name for this bad practice?  Is there a larger discussion of this idea within the context of "bad or misleading statistics" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of [base rate fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_rate_fallacy), because the missing information, which would make this much less misleading, is the absolute risk, or base rate, of being hit by lightning in general.